# Update a List from Form while avoiding duplicates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am new to SharePoint I searched but found no answers.

I have a Member List, 300+ entries, that is badly our of date, and new members are joining all the time.

We have an Infopath form which I've set up to, on button press, pull the user information directly from the company database (name, email, etc.) and auto fill most of their information. They then submit the form to the list.

This is great for new members, but we would like to use the same form for existing members to update their information. I'm concerned that them simply submitting the form will cause duplicates in the list.

Is there a way for users who are already in the list to update their info with this form, not just create a duplicate listing in the Members list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility for doing this might be editing the configuration for whichever column is the truly unique identifier for the member so that it must be unique.

Go to the list and on the List tab of the SharePoint page select ***List Setting***. Then under the ***Columns*** section click the name of column for which you would like to enforce unique values. On the ***Edit Column*** page change the ***Enforce unique values*** setting to ***Yes***.

Comment: The only truly unique column is the employee number, which is entered into a People Picker, which then populates the form. Will the fact that it's a people picker affect things?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.